# Ant, sudo and copynot working

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ant, sudo, go-cd

I am a newbie in ant. I am trying to do a simple deployment of index.html using GoCD. Basically I am trying to copy file from one folder to /var/www/html (which basically requires sudo permission to do). Here's my ant script:

```
<project name="My Project" default="help" basedir=".">
<condition property="rootTasksEnabled">
   <equals arg1="ec2-user" arg2="root" />
</condition>
<target name="copy" description="Copy New Web Page" if="rootTasksEnabled">
    <copy file="/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/Test-Pipeline/index.html" todir="/var/www/html"/>
</target>
</project>
```

I am trying to build this build.xml, deployment is successful, but file is not copied as scripted.

I have tried replacing copy target with the following:

```
<project name="My Project" default="help" basedir=".">
  <condition property="rootTasksEnabled">
     <equals arg1="ec2-user" arg2="root" />
  </condition>
  <copy todir="/var/www/html" flatten="true" if="rootTasksEnabled">
     <resources>
       <file file="/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/Test-Pipeline/index.html"/>
     </resources>
  </copy>
</project>
```

Here the error is thrown like "BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/Test-Pipeline/build.xml:5: copy doesn't support the "if" attribute"

Can someone please help me as I am stuck with no proper directions to go. What I want to achieve is copy file to a folder with sudo permission.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Ant documentation on the [Copy task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html), you'll notice that under 'Parameters' and further under the 'Attributes' column, the 'if' attribute is not supported inside a call to the Copy task- hence the error message that you are receiving: "BUILD FAILED /var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/Test-Pipeline/build.xml:5: copy doesn't support the "if" attribute".

May I suggest trying the following:

```
<project name="My Project" default="help" basedir=".">
 <condition property="rootTasksEnabled">
  <equals arg1="ec2-user" arg2="root" />
 </condition>
 <if>
  <isset property="rootTasksEnabled" />
  <then>
   <copy todir="/var/www/html" flatten="true">
    <resources>
     <file file="/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/Test-Pipeline/index.html"/>
    </resources>
   </copy>
  </then>
 </if>
</project>
```

Instead of embedding an 'if' condition inside the call to the Copy task (because it is unsupported), an alternative approach is to utilize the if/then tasks.

*NOTE: This approach does require the use of Ant Contrib

Answer (score 0):

the "sudo cp" can be implemented this way:

```
   <exec executable="/usr/bin/sudo">
        <arg value="cp"/>
        <arg value="${name}.war"/>
        <arg value="${deploy.path}"/>
    </exec>
```

it's not x-platform / portable, but does the job for linux